# Permanently disable the 'run in terminal' option

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I created a plain C++ with Qt program. I failed to achieve any application output. The fix for me was to disable the 'run in terminal' option in Qt Creator.

Anyway, I'd rather use the built-in application output pane for output than a separate terminal. I know I can change it per build configuration, but can make it disabled by default?

I'm using Qt Creator 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Default state of this option depends on your project file.

For **qmake**, if you have **CONFIG += console** - then this checkbox is checked.

For **qbs** it's **consoleApplication: true**

If you want different behavior for new projects - you can create your own [Qt Creator project wizard template](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html).